# delete specific quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, quotes

Now I am gonna to edit this :

```
var coordinates = [
         {"lat": 37.772, "lng": -122.214, "status": "walking"},
         {"lat": 36.772, "lng": -123.214, "status: "walking"}
         ];
```

And I use the replace function like this:

```
JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\"/g, "");
```

But after I replace the double quotes to "", the value walking's double quotes also got deleted, but I want the value walking can keep the quotes so js could regard it as string.

Comment: WTH would you want to remove any quotes from JSON strings, making it invalid in every way?

Comment: First of all, why do you need this? You already got a valid JS code. Second thing: you are missing a quote after `"status`.

Comment: For setting it as a js object, then I can set path for the js google map.

Comment: @WenhanHou: It already *is* a JS object.

Comment: Does that make sense? I mean, I want to remove the quotes then use it to set path for the map.

Comment: Sorry I am new to js, what I got in the google map api, the format looks like this: var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];

Comment: @WenhanHou: That's no different. In JS, you can optionally use quotes around property names. They're required when the property isn't a valid property identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all properties and remove quotes around it with this regex: `/"([a-z]*?)":/ig`. Keeping the string values with quotes.

```
var coordinates = [
     {"lat": 37.772, "lng": -122.214, "status": "walking"},
     {"lat": 36.772, "lng": -123.214, "status": "walking"}
];

var x = JSON.stringify(coordinates);

x.replace(/"([a-z]*?)":/ig, (m, m1) => m1 + ':');
```

Before

```
[{"lat":37.772,"lng":-122.214,"status":"walking"},{"lat":36.772,"lng":-123.214,"status":"walking"}]
```

After

```
[{lat:37.772,lng:-122.214,status:"walking"},{lat:36.772,lng:-123.214,status:"walking"}]
```